# PayFort Payment Gateway Token Request In Android

Tags: payfort

In PayFort payment gateway we have service_command parameter for TOKEN Request.

Now what i have to fill in values field for "service_command" parameter in TOKEN REQUEST call?

Comment: In , https://docs.payfort.com/docs/mobile-sdk/build/index.html#sdk-token-request link the reference is not good enough to perform Token call in PayFort

Comment: This Url is i used to get the PayFort Token.

 https://sbpaymentservices.payfort.com/FortAPI/paymentApi

Comment: Post Data :-

{
    "service_command": "SDK_TOKEN",
    "merchant_identifier": "---------",
    "access_code": "------------",
    "signature": "-----------------",
    "device_id": "--------",
    "language": "en"
}

Comment: Response :-

{
    "response_code": "00040",
    "response_message": "Invalid transaction source",
    "service_command": "SDK_TOKEN",
    "device_id": "----------",
    "signature": "--------------",
    "merchant_identifier": "------------",
    "access_code": "-------------",
    "language": "en",
    "status": "00"
}